# Added functionality broke my tests - very simple logic too

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd

I have code similar to this:

```
public List<string> Expected = new List<string>();
public int SpecifiedID;

public DataIn(int ID, string Value)
{
  Expected.Add(Value);
  //if (ID == SpecifiedID)
  //Expected.Clear();  

  //Need to add this but my tests that do something like      
  //CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { "2", "4", "6", "8" }, logic.Expected);
  //all fail as Expected is empty.
}

//Example Test
[Test]
public void NewTestFunction()
{
   MyClass logic = new MyClass();   
   logic.SpecifiedID = 4;

   logic.DataIn(1,"2"); 
   logic.DataIn(2,"4"); 
   logic.DataIn(3,"6"); 
   logic.DataIn(4,"8"); 

   //This will FAIL if Expected.Clear is added in the class.
   CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { "2", "4", "6", "8" }, logic.Expected);
}
```

This is simplified a lot however I have tests that check the validity of the `Expected` contents when `DataIn` is called. However I now have realised I have to clear `Expected` after every `DataIn` call. This has broken my tests obviously as there is nothing in it to assert against.

Any suggestions on how to keep the tests that validate the contents but also allow me to empty the collection?

Comment: Which tests? This is not answerable.

Comment: I have tests that do asserts such as             CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { "2", "4", "6", "8" }, logic.ExpectedValues); If I add Expected.Clear in my method these types of test fail.

Comment: Most unit test frameworks have a setup/teardown mechanism which is run between all unit tests.

Comment: This has broken your tests because the method logic is not the same anymore. Rewrite your test to match what the method actually does.

Comment: @ken2k I want to but I dont see how I can, hence the question

Comment: Does the call to `Clear()` have to happen in main code for a functional reason? Or are you adding the call so you can reset to a clean state between tests? If it is the first case, than the contract of your function has change, therefore what your test assert should change. If it is the first case, than you likely have a problem with the way your are running your test. Each test should be independent of each other. This can be done by using a new instance of `MyClass` for every test.

Comment: DataIn is the public method in the class. When the SpecifiedID is matched everything has to be cleared so that when the next call is made it starts adding data to it again ready for validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple - your code does not pass your test. I.e. it does not behave as expected (you describe expected behavior in your test). So, code should change - remove call to Expected.Clear(). Or think about what you expect from your code.

UPDATE (for case when expectations changes):

```
public void ShoulHaveAllDataInWhenIdIsNotSpecifiedID()
{
   MyClass logic = new MyClass();   
   logic.SpecifiedID = 3;

   logic.DataIn(1,"2"); 
   logic.DataIn(2,"4");     

   CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { "2", "4" }, logic.Expected);
}

[Test]
public void ShoulClearAllDataWhenSpecifiedIDPassed()
{
   MyClass logic = new MyClass();   
   logic.SpecifiedID = 3;

   logic.DataIn(1,"2"); 
   logic.DataIn(2,"4"); 
   logic.DataIn(3,"6");     

   CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { }, logic.Expected);
}
```

Also consider doing behavior testing instead of state testing. By providing mocks to your class you can check how it interacts with them. I.e. check what data passed to your class dependency.

Comment: I need Expected.Clear in my code! This is over simplified but I do need to clear it down

Comment: @Jon: Then you completely changed the logic of your method and you need to adjust your tests...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Agreed, that is what I'm failing to ask. How can I rewrite the example test in the question?

Comment: Your test is specification to code. It says that all data should be there after adding. So, something has changed - either specification changed (and you need to update expectations of class behavior), or class changed an specification is not satisfied any more (and you need to fix class implementation).

Comment: I agree. The method logic is not the same anymore, so tests must be re-written to test what the method actually does now.

Comment: @Jon: That's impossible to say without seeing the real code. However, if you clear the data from `Expected` before `DataIn` returns, there is no way to test it...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That's what I'm afraid of. The only thing I could possibly do is test the contents of it before the final DataIn is called but thats not ideal

Comment: About your last edits - you can update specification like 'all data should be in when class in some state'. Thats the part where specification changes. But you also should have test 'all data is cleared when class in other state'

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I can see that however I can never test the final result of Expected because it will be cleared. I have a test to check that its cleared in other state

Answer (score 1):

Initialization to known good state should be part of your test/class setup method.  From your description, though, it seems like you may have too much coupling between your tests or that your tests are testing too much at one time.  Each test, with appropriate set up, should be independent and ideally able to run in parallel.  Typically this means that each is running against a different instance of the class under test and you don't have dependencies on global data, or at least those dependencies are read-only so you can set it once for all tests.

Answer (score 1):

> When the SpecifiedID is matched everything has to be cleared

This is one test. Instantiate your object. Give it a SpecifiedId of X. Call DataIn() on it with Y as a first parameter and then with X as a first parameter. Assert that Expected is empty. Simple.

> when the next call is made it starts adding data to it again ready for
>   validation

This is another test. Instantiate your object. Give it a SpecifiedId of X. Repeatedly call DataIn() on it never using X as an ID. Assert that Expected contains the passed values. Simple.

Two requirements, two tests. Really, I can't see what's the big deal here.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not just change test function. Create a **new** test function:

```
[Test]
public void NewTestFunction()
{
    Data("Bla"); 

    //Test for something


    Expected.Clear();
}
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: I'm asking how can I run my tests to assert against Expected even though Expected.Clear() needs to be added to the logic. The tests will fail as Expected is empty.

Comment: @Jon: infact in my code the test is executed *before* collection cleared

Comment: Yes but Expected.Clear needs to go in the DataIn routine in the class under test. I have updated my question

Comment: @Jon: well, if so you need to change you test code definitely as the code it tests was changed. Do not adapt code in a way that test can work, but adapt tests to a *new* code. This is kind of anoying, but having test is not free of charge, it's more or less like mange a lightweight branch of your project.